# Jenkins cucumber reports

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm using [Cucumber reports plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cucumber-reports/) in my declarative pipeline like that:

```
cucumber '**/cucumber.json'
```

I'm able to check if some tests fail through link on the sidebar, but do I need to do something to mark the stage containing `cucumber.json` check as failed if some cucumber reports are failed? Because the problem is the build and stage are both green and successful despite there are some failed cucumber reports.

Jenkins version is 2.176.3

Cucumber reports version is 4.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set `BuildStatus : 'FAILURE'` to mark build as failed if a report marked as failed.

`cucumber fileIncludePattern: '**/cucumber.json', buildStatus: 'FAILURE'`

Comment: build status is not changing. with this cucumber option  buildStatus: .  any idea  whats wrong ?   always { cucumber fileIncludePattern:'**/target/*.json', buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE' }                  [build status change working with  currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'  ]

Comment: @chandu 
1) Specified status will be set when the report is marked as failed or unstable. Did you check if you have a failed/unstable report? 
2) Your file include pattern looks weird. It will be search a file named exactly `.json` at  `target` directory, nested at another directory. For example, `dir/target/.json` would match. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: sorry its typo in my above comment . file pattern is correct fileIncludePattern: '**/target/*.json' .  i could able to see report and also there are failed reports. but no change in jenkins build status.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber command you are using just generates the report regardless the test result.
So yes, you have to make your pipeline fail somehow as the problem you are facing is that your test command is not returning making your pipeline fail.

The way to go is to make that the command that runs the tests returns non-zero exit code (exit 1) if something went wrong on your tests. That would make your pipeline stage to go red.

In case you run your tests using Maven this would be automatically managed on 'mvn test' (or whatever).
Otherwise, if you cannot do that, you will have to manage to make something like for example an sh script
that returns the exit code (0 pass / 1 fail) or a groovy function inside 'script' tag that sets the pipeline currentBuild.result value:

```
def checkTestResult() {
    // Check some file to see if tests went fine or not
    return 'SUCCESS' // or 'FAILURE'
}
...
stage {
    script {
        currentBuild.result = checkTestResult()
        if (currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE') {
            sh "exit 1" // Force pipeline exit with build result failed
        }
    }
}
...
```

I recommend you to use cucumber command on a 'always' post build action of your declarative pipeline
as it is a step that you will likely execute every time at the end of the pipeline either if it passes or fails. See the following example:

```
pipeline {

    stages {
        stage('Get code') {
            // Whatever
        }
        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                sh "mvn test" // run_tests.sh or groovy code
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            cucumber '**/cucumber.json'
        }
    }
}
```